# Valid JSON, npm install

Tags: json, node.js, shell, npm

Thanks Guys for the help so far. But it is still not working, has anyone maybe another idea?

I'm using Sublime Text and did save with encoding UTF-8 (without the BOM) tag, but error stays the same.

```
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

i think this command has worked for me now im waiting for the installation and will try it again

error is still the same :(

but not sure i succesfully installed npm at the end it says

```
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/misc/semver.md html/doc/misc/semver.html
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/misc/npm-index.md html/doc/index.html
node cli.js install -g -f
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN cannot run in wd npm@1.3.14 node bin/npm-cli.js prune --prefix=. --no-global && rm -rf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j4 doc (wd=.)
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@1.3.14 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma:

```
{
    "name": "node-todo",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Simple todo application",
    "main": "server.js",
    "author": "Ludwig Kaube",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.4.4",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.2"
    }, 
    "private": true
}
```

Everything else looks good.

**Correction**: As pointed out, `dependencies` was also mispelled.

Comment: `dependecies` should be `dependencies`

Comment: did you fix what @ExplosionPills pointed out too? I just updated my answer.

Comment: hmm, I just did the install, and it worked for me. Also, you appear to have left the `//<- Here!` in according to the error message. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: it keeps getting the same error :( i updated again the question above this is the current state.

Comment: is it possible i haven't made sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

Comment: like it is said when finishing installation of Node.js

Comment: no, this is definitely a `JSON` parse error caused by `/` in your JSON. At least according to the error. it's definitely not a path issue since it's running.

Comment: but you guys see no error in den .json file? damn i even fail before the start

Comment: Now i get it. See this bug report for a problem like yours https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3358.

Comment: as above said, i save it with sublime a a utf 8 .json but error stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link to validate your package.json file. It might work after that

http://package-json-validator.com/

You can also visit this link to see how to write package.json file

https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Now i get the problem. See this [bug report](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3358). What it means that, you should set up your text editor to save files in UTF-8, without a byte-order-mark. Or better you use a different text editor. The code is fine. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks, but it says vaild:true just some warnings do i have do add them?

Comment: give it a try, best of luck.

Comment: "warnings": [
    "Missing recommended field: keywords",
    "Missing recommended field: bugs",
    "Missing recommended field: licenses",
    "Missing recommended field: contributors",
    "Missing recommended field: repository"
  ],

Comment: but i have no idea what to write in them, i will put some empty strings into

Comment: Are you sure you're using npm and not CommonJS package?

Comment: well i downloaded node.js and type into npm install? how do i see the difference?

Comment: for writing against those warning, take a hint from the link 'sample:this package' on top left of the 'enter the contents' text-area of the site.

Comment: ah ok even if i want to npm install the sample package the same error occurs, so i think the problem is with my npm install, i only did install node.js do i have to install npm install seperatly?

Comment: Yes, to install npm in one command, you can do this:

curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

Comment: does not work, i updated my text above to show what the shell says